# In google-app-engine: How to query all entries after specific date in GQL

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datetime, gql

I'm trying to run a simple query from my java application:

```
SELECT * FROM Schedule where date > DATETIME(2013,11,10)
```

if get the following error JSON response:

```
03-06 14:03:13.730: W/System.err(13272): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
03-06 14:03:13.730: W/System.err(13272): {
03-06 14:03:13.730: W/System.err(13272):   "code" : 503,
03-06 14:03:13.730: W/System.err(13272):   "errors" : [ {
03-06 14:03:13.730: W/System.err(13272):     "domain" : "global",
03-06 14:03:13.730: W/System.err(13272):     "message" : "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Problem with query <SELECT FROM Schedule as Schedule WHERE date > DATETIME(2013,11,10)>: Unsupported method <DATETIME> while parsing expression: InvokeExpression{STATIC.DATETIME(Literal{2013}, Literal{11}, Literal{10})}",
03-06 14:03:13.730: W/System.err(13272):     "reason" : "backendError"
03-06 14:03:13.730: W/System.err(13272):   } ],
03-06 14:03:13.730: W/System.err(13272):   "message" : "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Problem with query <SELECT FROM Schedule as Schedule WHERE date > DATETIME(2013,11,10)>: Unsupported method <DATETIME> while parsing expression: InvokeExpression{STATIC.DATETIME(Literal{2013}, Literal{11}, Literal{10})}"
03-06 14:03:13.730: W/System.err(13272): }
```

this exact query works just fine when i run it from the admin console on app engine website
'date' is a DateTime field and i have an index for it.
on the app engine website the field looks like this: "2014-04-13 00:00:00"

here is my code:

```
    EntityManager mgr = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    List<Schedule> execute = null;

    try {
        mgr = getEntityManager();
        Query query = mgr.createQuery("select from Schedule as Schedule "
                                    + "where date > DATETIME(2013,11,10)");
        if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "") {
            cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
            query.setHint(JPACursorHelper.CURSOR_HINT, cursor);
        }

        if (limit != null) {
            query.setFirstResult(0);
            query.setMaxResults(limit);
        }

        execute = (List<Schedule>) query.getResultList();
        cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

        // Tight loop for fetching all entities from datastore and accomodate
        // for lazy fetch.
        for (Schedule obj : execute)
            ;
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }

    return CollectionResponse.<Schedule> builder().setItems(execute)
            .setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
```

any help would me greatly appreciated